# How to use multiple Jasypt encryptors in a Spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasypt

I have a **Spring-boot** project in which I'm using **jasypt** for encrypting the properties in my yaml file. So far, I'm using **single password** for all the encryption and providing the password through `jasypt.encryptor.password` at runtime. Now as the requirements have changed, I need to encrypt **credentials** in **different profiles** with **different passwords**. Also, I need to encrypt some common properties which'll be used by all the profiles.

So my question is, can we provide **multiple encryptors** to encrypt **different profiles** and provide the password for only the required ones at runtime? I'm thinking of using **different prefix and suffix** for each of them.

But as far as I've got, I think **jasypt-spring-boot** is **hard-coded** to look for `jasypt.encryptor.password` to **automatically decrypt** the values.

So can anyone throw some light on **feasibility** of approach I'm thinking and if `jasypt-spring-boot` got it covered for me? Also shed light on possible solutions to my problem. Thanks!